# WSS 2.0 lifecycle (when does support stop?)

Tags: sharepoint, lifecycle, wss

When will Microsoft stop supporting WSS **2.0**? For my current project we have the choice to migrate our code to WSS 3.0 or continue to use WSS 2.0. Depending on Microsoft's support policy our customer will have to make a choice.

I already looked on the [Microsoft Lifecycle website](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=nl&p1=2528&x=14&y=13), but WSS 2.0 isn't listed. Maybe WSS 2.0 is considered a part of Windows 2000 Server and has the same lifecycle policy?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, already found it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=7022)...